# Dagger2 does not generate components in Test

Tags: robolectric, dagger-2

As per the Dagger 2 documentation

I am trying to set up a test environment according to [Dagger2's documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html)

(Just for context, I have successfully done this in Dagger 1.)

The problem, specifically, is that while Dagger2 correctly generates DaggerRoboDaggerComponent (as used in App.java), it does not generate DaggerTestRoboDaggerComponent (as used in MainActivityTest.java).  I have checked the directory structure to make sure it's not hiding in some obscure place, and done the requisite clean, rebuild, Invalidate Caches / Restart, etc.

If someone could please let me know the error of my ways, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

You can [clone the project here](https://bitbucket.org/shonshampain/robodagger)

Or, browse thru the project files below:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.robodagger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.1"
}
```

App.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {

    static RoboDaggerComponent roboDaggerComponent;
    static RoboDaggerComponent getComponent() {
        return roboDaggerComponent;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        roboDaggerComponent = DaggerRoboDaggerComponent.builder()
            .roboDaggerModule(new RoboDaggerModule())
            .build();
    }

}
```

Foo.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

class Foo {
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "foo";
   }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject Foo foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        App.getComponent().inject(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(foo.toString());
    }
}
```

RoboDaggerComponent.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules={RoboDaggerModule.class})
interface RoboDaggerComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

RoboDaggerModule.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Module
class RoboDaggerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Foo providesFoo() { return new Foo(); }
}
```

And now in the test directory,

FakeFoo.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

class FakeFoo extends Foo {

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

MainActivityTest.java

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    TestRoboDaggerComponent testRoboDaggerComponent;

    @Inject Foo foo;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        testRoboDaggerComponent = DaggerTestRoboDaggerComponent.builder()
            .testRoboDaggerModule(new TestRoboDaggerModule())
            .build();
        testRoboDaggerComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void fooBarTest() {
        assert(foo.toString().equals("bar"));
    }
}
```

TestRoboDaggerComponent.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules={TestRoboDaggerModule.class})
interface TestRoboDaggerComponent {

    void inject(MainActivityTest mainActivityTest);
}
```

TestRoboDaggerModule.java

```
package xx.robodagger;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Module
class TestRoboDaggerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Foo providesFoo() { return new FakeFoo(); }
}
```

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself you should _answer_ your own question and accept your own answer.

Comment: RoboDaggerModule and TestRoboDaggerModule are different classes though. How will .roboDaggerModule(new TestRoboDaggerModule()) work?

Comment: Does TestRoboDaggerModule extend RoboDaggerModule?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the omission. TestRoboDaggerModule extends RoboDaggerModule. You can add test specific items there.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `TestRoboDaggerComponent.java`, it's not needed

Modify `App.java` to setup the component via a protected method

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setupComponent();
}

protected void setupComponent() {
    roboDaggerComponent = DaggerRoboDaggerComponent.builder()
            .roboDaggerModule(new RoboDaggerModule())
            .build();
}
```

Modify `TestApp.java` to extend `App`, and override the previously mentioned method with the TestModule

```
public class TestApp extends App {

    @Override
    protected void setupComponent() {
        roboDaggerComponent = DaggerRoboDaggerComponent.builder()
            .roboDaggerModule(new TestRoboDaggerModule())
            .build();
    }
}
```

And finally, in the actual test, leverage Robolectric's power to specify the Application module

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,
        application = TestApp.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void fooBarTest() {
        TextView tv = (TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        assert(tv.getText().equals("bar"));
    }
}
```

Notice that there isn't any DI in the actual test proper. The injection of MainActivity takes place as expected, and with the overridden module. If you have a dependency that uses @Injects in the constructor, the solution per Dagger's documentation is *not* to use injection in the test, but to just call the normal constructor with mocked objects.  This all makes sense. I still think the originally reported issue is a bug, but whatever.